# How to multiply 2 columns?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dataexplorer

I'm making a Query on [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com):

```
SELECT
  Name,
  COUNT(*) Qty,
  Points = CASE Name
    WHEN 'Altruist' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Analytical' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Announcer' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Autobiographer' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Benefactor' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Caucus' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Citizen Patrol' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Cleanup' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Commentator' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Critic' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Custodian' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Disciplined' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Editor' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Excavator' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Informed' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Investor' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Mortarboard' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Nice Answer' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Nice Question' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Organizer' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Peer Pressure' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Popular Question' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Precognitive' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Promotor' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Proofreader' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Quorum' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Revival' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Scholar' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Self-Learner' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Student' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Suffrage' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Supporter' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Synonymizer' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Tag Editor' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Talkative' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Teacher' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Tumbleweed' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Vox Populi' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Archaeologist' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Beta' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Booster' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Civic Duty' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Constituent' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Convention' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Deputy' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Enlightened' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Enthusiast' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Epic' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Favorite Question' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Generalist' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Good Answer' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Good Question' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Guru' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Necromancer' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Notable Question' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Outspoken' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Pundit' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Research Assistant' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Reviewer' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Sportsmanship' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Strunk & White' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Taxonomist' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Tenacious' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Yearling' THEN 10
    WHEN 'Copy Editor' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Electorate' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Famous Question' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Fanatic' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Great Answer' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Great Question' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Legendary' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Marshal' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Populist' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Publicist' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Reversal' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Stellar Question' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Steward' THEN 20
    WHEN 'Unsung Hero' THEN 20
    ELSE 0
  END,
  Qty * Points AS Total
FROM Badges
WHERE UserId = 1563422
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

This all works except for when `, Qty * Points AS Total` is added (take that away from the query above to [run the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103329/top-users-with-the-most-weighted-badges) successfully).

The error I get is:

> Invalid column name '`Qty`'.
>
> Invalid column name '`Points`'.

How can I multiply `Qty` and `Points` as `Total`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery, or a *CTE* like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT
    Name,
    COUNT(*) Qty,
    Points = CASE Name
      WHEN 'Altruist' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Analytical' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Announcer' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Autobiographer' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Benefactor' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Caucus' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Citizen Patrol' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Cleanup' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Commentator' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Critic' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Custodian' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Disciplined' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Editor' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Excavator' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Informed' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Investor' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Mortarboard' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Nice Answer' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Nice Question' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Organizer' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Peer Pressure' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Popular Question' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Precognitive' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Promotor' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Proofreader' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Quorum' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Revival' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Scholar' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Self-Learner' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Student' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Suffrage' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Supporter' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Synonymizer' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Tag Editor' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Talkative' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Teacher' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Tumbleweed' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Vox Populi' THEN 5
      WHEN 'Archaeologist' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Beta' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Booster' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Civic Duty' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Constituent' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Convention' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Deputy' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Enlightened' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Enthusiast' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Epic' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Favorite Question' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Generalist' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Good Answer' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Good Question' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Guru' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Necromancer' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Notable Question' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Outspoken' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Pundit' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Research Assistant' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Reviewer' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Sportsmanship' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Strunk & White' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Taxonomist' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Tenacious' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Yearling' THEN 10
      WHEN 'Copy Editor' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Electorate' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Famous Question' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Fanatic' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Great Answer' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Great Question' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Legendary' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Marshal' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Populist' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Publicist' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Reversal' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Stellar Question' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Steward' THEN 20
      WHEN 'Unsung Hero' THEN 20
      ELSE 0
    END
  FROM Badges
  WHERE UserId = 1563422
  GROUP BY Name
  )
  SELECT *, QTY * Points AS Total
  FROM CTE;
```

[**Updated Demo on Data Explorer**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103330/top-users-with-the-most-weighted-badges)

Comment: ...I don't suppose you might know how to get a `GrandTotal`? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26206/room-for-danny-beckett-and-mahmoud-gamal